# How to not affect the user experience when running a backend process in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a web app where users can upload huge excel sheets which is then processed in the backend. Once the user uploads the excel file it takes almost 5-10 mins to complete the whole processing. So currently what I have done is when clicking a button the link it to the function which makes the page freeze as the backend process is still running.

My question is how can I separate the flask application from this process function?

The python is being run in Cpanel.

Comment: UX is not a good topic for Stack Overflow. But there's a special site in the Stack Exchange network: [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's not about UX. It's about how can I separate a function from a flask main function.

Comment: Then you might want to rephrase your question.